# example of pdf creator

Tags: ios4

I have generated pdf programatically bt problem is text doesnt appear in pdf. PLz provide me simple example of pdf creator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple create pdf file with hard code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276030/simple-create-pdf-file-with-hard-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend these libraries:

http://itextpdf.com/download.php
or
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop/

It comes with examples.